# westend network try to send transfer transaction but fail

Tags: transactions

my westend account is 5G7NsFf3MqwEKSbuo52d2Y9RaaiMQ3akXzSWpSvgUYq3ZEsm.
it shows I have 0.02 WND, and I try to use Balances.transfer or transfer_allow_death  0.0035 WND to another account.

So I send 3500000000 out,  but I got error Invalid Transaction: Inability to pay some fees , e.g. account balance too low.

I remains 0.0165 WND to pay fee. why I got this error?

Answer (score 1):

The error is clearly stated as `Inability to pay some fees`, indicating that the remaining balance is insufficient to cover the fee.

1. It is just not enough for the fee
2. Sometimes there might be some balance locks on your account